# upgrade to openssl 1.0.1e on windows

Tags: windows, path, openssl

I know I am missing a crucial step, but I can't figure out what to do

I have openssl `OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007`

I downloaded openssl for win32 and installed it in `c:\openssl`

I added `c:\openssl\bin` to my path before any other folders but I still don't get version 1.0.1e when I do `openssl version` in commandline

Where is openssl (the original) located and how do I tell windows to start using the new one?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention which Windows version you're using. If it's Windows Server 2003 or later, then the following command should give you `openssl`'s path:

```
where openssl
```

Your version is the same as the one that's included with Git. If it is Git and nothing else works, then you can try to rename Git's `openssl.exe` and symlink the new one in its place using `mklink`. Be careful though, you can break Git by doing this.

Comment: so upgrading git should upgrade openssl?

Comment: I think latest Git uses that outdated version of OpenSSL, so you should rather try experimenting with PATH or that symlink trick.

Comment: I see this when I do `where openssl` `C:\openssl\bin\openssl.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\openssl.exe` so windows recognizes it..

Comment: Have you tried running the newer one explicitly: `C:\openssl\bin\openssl version`?